# xtreg omitting year dummy variables when using i.year

Tags: stata

I have a panel dataset with the following years:

```
tab year

       year |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
       2000 |         31       12.55       12.55
       2001 |         31       12.55       25.10
       2002 |         30       12.15       37.25
       2003 |         31       12.55       49.80
       2004 |         31       12.55       62.35
       2005 |         31       12.55       74.90
       2006 |         31       12.55       87.45
       2007 |         31       12.55      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |        247      100.00
```

When I do `xtreg dv iv i.year`, I see that year `2000` is not included, as well as `2007`:

```
xtreg local_gr rtxdum i.year
note: 2007.year omitted because of collinearity

Random-effects GLS regression                   Number of obs     =        247
Group variable: province_n~e                    Number of groups  =         31

R-sq:                                           Obs per group:
     within  = 0.6194                                         min =          7
     between = 0.0016                                         avg =        8.0
     overall = 0.2356                                         max =          8

                                                Wald chi2(7)      =     341.51
corr(u_i, X)   = 0 (assumed)                    Prob > chi2       =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    local_gr |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      rtxdum |  -753799.7   291543.7    -2.59   0.010     -1325215   -182384.5
             |
        year |
       2001  |     388246   291543.7     1.33   0.183    -183169.2    959661.2
       2002  |   745406.4   294294.5     2.53   0.011     168599.8     1322213
       2003  |    1175610   291543.7     4.03   0.000     604194.4     1747025
       2004  |    1773982   291543.7     6.08   0.000      1202567     2345397
       2005  |    2600005   291543.7     8.92   0.000      2028589     3171420
       2006  |    4425318   291543.7    15.18   0.000      3853903     4996734
       2007  |          0  (omitted)
             |
       _cons |    1564670   447832.4     3.49   0.000     686934.1     2442405
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |  2217878.8
     sigma_e |  1150064.9
         rho |  .78809251   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The message says `2007` was omitted due to collinearity, but I don't understand why year `2000` would not show up in the results?

Comment: As @PearlySpencer hints, you are always -- with this syntax going to see results for one fewer indicator (dummy) variable than you throw into a regression. Why 2007 is omitted as well is collinearity in your dataset. This is a question of statistical understanding. Lack of research is evident.

Comment: @NickCox Clearly you did not read the question, I said that the results are omitting two years, not one. 2000 and 2007. So it's not one fewer, two fewer. I don't get why I have to explain myself again in this comment.

Comment: I did read _and_ understand the question. To repeat: always going to see one fewer indicator (that's one); 2007 is omitted as well because of collinearity in your dataset (that's two in your case). .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is the base level. You can see it by using the `allbaselevels` option:

```
webuse nlswork, clear
xtset idcode

xtreg ln_w grade tenure i.race not_smsa south, allbaselevels


Random-effects GLS regression                   Number of obs     =     28,091
Group variable: idcode                          Number of groups  =      4,697

R-sq:                                           Obs per group:
     within  = 0.1005                                         min =          1
     between = 0.4498                                         avg =        6.0
     overall = 0.3305                                         max =         15

                                                Wald chi2(6)      =    6509.50
corr(u_i, X)   = 0 (assumed)                    Prob > chi2       =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ln_wage |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       grade |     .07605   .0018128    41.95   0.000     .0724969    .0796031
      tenure |   .0361319   .0006298    57.37   0.000     .0348975    .0373663
             |
        race |
      white  |          0  (base)
      black  |  -.0530121   .0102916    -5.15   0.000    -.0731832   -.0328409
      other  |   .0762678   .0415911     1.83   0.067    -.0052492    .1577849
             |
    not_smsa |  -.1289554   .0074296   -17.36   0.000    -.1435172   -.1143936
       south |  -.0786512   .0075533   -10.41   0.000    -.0934555    -.063847
       _cons |   .6759773   .0244723    27.62   0.000     .6280125    .7239421
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |  .26440074
     sigma_e |  .30295598
         rho |  .43235646   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```